# Magento Change Product image while adding product to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, image, product-images, addtocart

I want to **change product image  after a user added a product in to cart**, Because user can change image text and font style. So, I have loaded Quote item using event `sales_quote_add_item` and I am able to change product price using it but I am not getting how to change product image.

Comment: Which version of magento are you using ?

Comment: Magento CE 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cart product image is provided by the `getProductThumbnail` method from the following renderers:

- `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer_Configurable` for configurable products
- `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer_Grouped` for grouped products
- `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer` for any other type of products

Thus, my advice would be to rewrite those renderer blocks in a module:

`config.xml`

```
<modules>
    <DigitalPianism_CartImage>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </DigitalPianism_CartImage>
</modules>

<global>

    <blocks>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <!-- Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer -->
                <cart_item_renderer>DigitalPianism_CartImage_Block_Checkout_Cart_Item_Renderer</cart_item_renderer>
                <!-- Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer_Configurable -->
                <cart_item_renderer_configurable>DigitalPianism_CartImage_Block_Checkout_Cart_Item_Renderer_Configurable</cart_item_renderer_configurable>
                <!-- Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer_Grouped -->
                <cart_item_renderer_grouped>DigitalPianism_CartImage_Block_Checkout_Cart_Item_Renderer_Grouped</cart_item_renderer_grouped>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </blocks>

</global>
```

NB: you change remove some rewrites from this file if you don't need them (i.e. if you don't use configurable products, remove the corresponding block rewrite, same for grouped products)

Then you can create your custom blocks extending the original blocks.

Here's a sample of how your code could look like for the `DigitalPianism_CartImage_Block_Checkout_Cart_Item_Renderer` block:

```
<?php

class DigitalPianism_CartImage_Block_Checkout_Cart_Item_Renderer extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer
{

    public function getProductThumbnail()
    {
        if () {
        } else {
            return parent::getProductThumbnail();
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that as I don't know exactly what will trigger the image change, you will have to update the if statement of the above code to match your needs

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will implement this thing and let you know its working or not

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the quote item does not stores the product image as it does for the product price.

Although you can store the url info of the image using the `setProductOption` method of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item`.

Once the data is saved, for the cart page you can overwrite `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Item_Renderer` classes `getProductThumbnail` method to fetch the item option data saved previously.